# Android Simple ToDo list app not rendering correctly

Tags: android, listview

Am following the tutorial here on creating a simple todo list app:
http://www.mydroid.apnafundaz.com/2010/07/todolist-application-in-android-step-by-step-guide-with-screen-shots/

Have completed and have no errors, however my app doesn't appear like in that example, rather it looks like this  - basically the EditText appears, but there's no ListView with previous tasks...

As there's no errors, it's rather hard to work out where I'm going wrong, but as my partner's also doing the same tutorial and has come up with exactly the same result, I am thinking there could be an issue with the tut - any advice much appreciated!

**Just in case, here's my java file:**

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HelloWorld extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate your view
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get references to UI widgets
    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

    // Create the array list of todo items
    final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Create the array adaptor to bind the array to the listview
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
             todoItems);

    // Bind the array adapter to the listview
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);

    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

     public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
      if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
       if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
       {
        todoItems.add(0,myEditText.getText().toString());
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        myEditText.setText("");
        return true;
       }
      return false;
     }


    }



    );



}
}
```

**And here's my main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/myEditText"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:text="New to Do Item"
    />
    <ListView
 android:id="@+id/myListView"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you following this awkward tutorial? It's not particularly good: it doesn't teach about `ListActivity`, it doesn't teach about data persistence, and the code is mostly poorly written and just bad. http://developer.android.com/ has a lot of nice tutorials, why not start there?

Comment: i have written a tutorial on TODO application in my blog.For details visit
http://www.harshaprabha.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one small change, in your `EditText` you are setting `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`. So you cannot see List view. Just change it to `wrap_content`

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/myEditText"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="New to Do Item"
    />
```

Comment: Ah genius - makes total sense! Works a treat now!

Comment: Thanks. Happy to know it help u :)

Answer (score 1):

KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER is an odd choice of keycode... are you actually pressing this to add the edittext contents to the list? It's an odd choice cos some phones don't have directional pads. Try changing it for KEYCODE_ENTER.

Comment: or better yet, use an OnKeyboardActionListener for when the action button is pressed...

Comment: Just following the tutorial man! ;) Good shout though, makes more sense what you guys are saying...

Answer (score 0):

On the first start, your list should be empty, because you have no previous todos defined. Have you tried to add a todo with the edittext? After that you should see it in the listview.